# Calculate and select max of a column in the same query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a dataset like this

```
+------+------------+------+
| user |    date    | code |
+------+------------+------+
|    1 | 2016-01-01 | AB   |
|    2 | 2016-02-03 | AS   |
|    3 | 2016-02-03 | AT   |
|    1 | 2016-01-27 | AB   |
|    2 | 2016-02-24 | AT   |
|    1 | 2016-01-23 | AS   |
|    2 | 2016-02-23 | AB   |
|    1 | 2016-02-16 | AS   |
|    1 | 2016-02-24 | AT   |
+------+------------+------+
```

And I need something like this

```
+------+---------------------------+
| user | max(count(distinct(code)) |
+------+---------------------------+
|    1 |                         2 |
|    2 |                         3 |
|    3 |                         1 |
+------+---------------------------+
```

So I used this query

```
select t1.user, t1.month(date), count(distinct(`code`)) cod
from mytable t1
inner join 
(select user, max(count(distinct(`code`))) max_count
from mytable
group by user) t2
on t1.user = t2.user
and t1.cod = t2.max_count`
```

But I get this:

> Error code 1111. Invalid use of group function

Comment: You cannot use multiple aggregates together like that.  I'm confused why user 1 returns 2 codes -- why not AB, AS and AT?

Comment: Because the idea is count the distinct every month and choose the max value of that count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, using a inner group by `user`, `month` and outer group by `user`.

```
select t.user, max(t.cod) as max_cnt
from (
    select user, month(date) as month, count(distinct(`code`)) cod
    from mytable
    group by user, month
    ) t
group by t.user
```

Comment: thanks @Dylan Su. I just have a question, why my query doesn't work?, it's for this "count(distinct(`code`)) cod" in the first part or why?

Comment: Use of two aggregate functions together is not allowed: max(count())

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```sql
select `user`, max(`max_count`)
from (
   select `user`, count(`code`) as `max_count`
   from `mytable`
   group by `user`, `code` ) t
group by `user`
```